# ViewGroup AnimationListener not firing

Tags: android

I'm removing a child from a parent with animateLayoutChanges on. I want to know when the animation is complete, but can't get the listener to fire:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/child" />

</LinearLayout>

void testRemove() {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.parent);
    parent.setLayoutAnimationListener(listener);

    TextView child = findViewById(R.id.child);
    child.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this triggers the animation.
}

Animation.AnimationListener listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // None of these callback methods fire.
    }
};
```

Any ideas why the listener wouldn't fire?

Thanks

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener)

-------- Update ------------------

A TransitionListener seems to work:

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = parent.getLayoutTransition();
layoutTransition.addTransitionListener(new TransitionListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout animation attribute in your LinearLayout xml,

Docs here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:layoutAnimation

add a file to your res/anim folder of `fade_in.xml`, this will be your fade animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
```

Then add a file to your res/anim folder of `layout_fade_in.xml` that has a reference to the fade animation `@anim/fade_in` you just made, this file will be used for `android:layoutAnimation` values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:delay="0.5"
        android:animation="@anim/fade_in" />
```

Now, change your LinearLayout xml slightly to include the `android:layoutAnimation` attribute and value

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_fade_in"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/child" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Made those changes but the animation listener still does not fire. I tried adding a TransitionListener and that is firing. Updated question with it.